# Popup blocker issue in Firefox in Ajax call under success

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am having an issue with popup blockers. I want to open a window for my users only after I receive some data from server, in other words I need it on success.

Issue is that popup blocker will stop the window in the success section as it thinks that script is currently executing. I am using jQuery 1.7.1.min and I have tried using (as you can see below)
`async:false`, but for some reason that doesn't work. The only workaround that I was able to do is to open a fake window and when the response comes back
overwrite the fake window. It works in Chrome but it gives problems in Firefox. Need some help.

```
function mypopup() {
    $j.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/my/phppage",
        data: mydata,
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            window.open(response, 'Dialogue Message', 'width=650,height=550,left=50,top=50,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
        }
    });
    window.open("openfakewindow", 'Dialogue Message', 'width=650,height=550,left=50,top=50,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is Firefox only allows popups if it is created from a user generated event, for example a click event.

You can get around this by opening a blank window before the Ajax call, keep a reference to it and then set the URL after the ajax call is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a dialogue box that is essentially a  element that you identify and then open?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divAccountDialog").dialog(
            {
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 700,
                buttons: { Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
            }

        );
    });
```

someotherfunction () {
         $('#divAccountDialog').dialog('open');